# Scroll to particular Text view inside the Scroll view

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview, android-scrollview

There is a program generated scroll view like this:

The scroll view XML is just simple empty LinearLayout

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then , in the run time , I have an `ArrayList<TextView>`, and add the items to the ScrollView like this

```
for (TextView t : test_views) {
     scroll_view.addView(t);
}
```

And now , I have one of the listView and I would like to scroll to that TextView programmatic , the case is quite special so that can not change the scrollview to listview, how to achieve that?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using scrollTo() function. More details available in this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo(int, int)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code.

```
sv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                tv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                return false;
            }
        });

tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                tv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Hope it will help you.

Let me know if you need any further help.